# Ionic 3 - ngFor data blank in second access

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

I have a problem with ngFor in Ionic 3, in first access I get correct data in ngFor, but in second access the data don't load correctly (in console, the data is loaded).

```
 ngOnInit() { 
  this.loadFeedbacks().then((feedbacks) => {
  this.feedbacks = feedbacks;
})
```

}

```
loadFeedbacks() {
   var feedbacks = [];
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  this.db.getFeedbacks(this.eventId).then((listFeedbacks: Array<any>) => {

    var size = listFeedbacks.length;
    var cont = 0;
    listFeedbacks.forEach(element => {
      this.db.checkUserResponseFeedback(element.uid, this.userId).then((response) => {
        if (response == false || element.change_answer == true) {
          switch (element.type) {
            case 'SpecificSession':
              if (this.sessionId == element.reference) {
                feedbacks.push(element);
                cont++;
              }
            break;

            case 'GroupOfAttendees':
              this.db.checkMemberTrackAttendee(element.reference, this.userId, (retorno) => {
                if (retorno == true) {
                  feedbacks.push(element);
                  cont++
                }
              })
            break;

            case 'SessionTrack':
              //Falta a implementação das tracks
              cont++;
            break;

            case 'AllSessions':
              feedbacks.push(element);
              cont++;
            break;
          }

          if (cont == size) {
            resolve(feedbacks)
          }
        }
      })
    })
  });

})
```

}

```
<div *ngFor="let feedback of feedbacks; let i = index;">
  <!-- ANGULAR BINDING HERE -->
</div>
```

> **Screenshots of first access:**
>
> [image: First access: data OK] [image: First access: Console data]
>
> **Screenshots of second access:**
>
> [image: Second access: data don't load] 
>   [image: Second access: Console data]

I read about Observables, but I don't understand how to apply to the project.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the feedbacks data isn't ready yet.Try to add `ngIf` to validate feedbacks

```
<ion-content>
  <div *ngIf="feedbacks.length > 0">
    // YOUR ngFor CODE
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Alternatively, convert Promise to Observable:

```
const feedbacks$: Observable<any[]>;
this.feedbacks$ = Observable.fromPromise(loadFeedbacks());
```

In HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let feedback of feedbacks$| async as feedbacks; let i = index;">
  <!-- ANGULAR BINDING HERE -->
</div>
```